# FsCheck.xUnit: testing types from another assembly

Tags: f#, xunit, fscheck

I'm trying to make my first test with FsCheck and xUnit. I have the following setup:

- An F# class library with a single file

  ```
  namespace Lib
  type ABC = A | B | C
  ```
- A project called Tests with a reference to FsCheck.xUnit NuGet package with a single file:

  ```
  module LibTests    
  open FsCheck.Xunit
  open Lib    
  [<Property>]
  let ``ABC is always A`` v =
    v = A
  ```

When I run the project (with VS or console runner), I get the following error:

```
System.Exception : The type Lib.ABC is not handled automatically by FsCheck. 
Consider using another type or writing and registering a generator for it
```

If I move my type to the Tests assembly, everything works fine (test fails). How do I tests external types?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears to be related to a known issue [described on FsCheck GitHub](https://github.com/fscheck/FsCheck/issues/187).

Basically, FsCheck NuGet package depends on the old version of FSharp.Core library. The old version gets referenced, which makes the test code incompatible to the system under test.

To fix the problem:

1. After you install FsCheck NuGet package, go to test project references and remove the reference to the old version of FSharp.Core (4.3.1.0 in my case).
2. Click "Add reference" to add it again, go to Assemblies -> Extensions and add FSharpCore of the same version that is used in your other projects, **4.4.0.0** in my case.
3. Add an `App.config` file to your test project with the following contents:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
   <configuration>
     <runtime>
       <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
         <dependentAssembly>
           <assemblyIdentity name="FSharp.Core" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
           <bindingRedirect oldVersion="4.3.1.0" newVersion="4.4.0.0" />
         </dependentAssembly>
       </assemblyBinding>
     </runtime>
   </configuration>
   ```

Comment: The binding redirect in App.config was exactly what I needed. Note that you can generalize it to ``<bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.4.0.0" newVersion="4.4.0.0">``

Answer (score 3):

First of all, when I run this, I do get different behaviour to you.  An example result from my test project:

> Result Message:    FsCheck.Xunit.PropertyFailedException :  Falsifiable,
>   after 4 tests (0 shrinks) (StdGen (196938613,296107830)): Original: B

This makes sense because fscheck should be capable of automatically creating a generator for a discriminated union type (such as `ABC`) via reflection, see: https://fscheck.github.io/FsCheck/TestData.html

I would therefore recommend checking all your packages are installed correctly and fully up to date.

I installed:

- FsCheck (v2.2.4)
- FsCheck.Xunit (v2.2.4)
- xunit (v2.1.0)

**FSharp.Core**

Always be careful when installing nuget packages which reference FSharp.Core as they are often distributed with a specific version which overwrites your project settings.

If this occurs, delete FSharp.Core from your packages.config file, delete the reference to FSharp.Core in your project and replace it with the desired version of FSharp.Core from the list of assemblies.  You can find FSharp.Core under extensions.

You can also redirect references to older FSharp.Core versions to a specified newer version using a binding redirect in your app.config file.

Using `<AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>true</AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>` in your .fsproj can generate such binding redirects automatically. See https://fsharp.github.io/2015/04/18/fsharp-core-notes.html for more details on  usage.

**Generators**

The error message you have refers to a capability fscheck where you can specify how arbitrary instances of your types are created for the purposes of property testing.  An example of a custom generator:

```
type MyGenerators =
    static member ABC() =
        {new Arbitrary<ABC>() with
            override x.Generator = gen { return A; } // generator that creates only A
            override x.Shrinker t = Seq.empty }
```

I can then use this generator to check my property:

```
[<Property(Arbitrary=[|typeof<MyGenerators>|])>]
static member ``ABC is always A`` v =
    v = A
```

This test now always passes because I have always specified that the generator creates an `A`.

Comment: Yes, I know that it should work, but it doesn't... If you have time, could you clone https://github.com/mikhailshilkov/FsCheckTest and run the tests (I use VS runner). I get same error on two machines.

Comment: @Mikhail I haven't checked out your repo yet but I do notice (by eye) that you have an FSharp.Core in your packages.config.  I wonder if your test project is using an older version of FSharp.Core than your main project.  I recommend that you delete the one from your packages.config, remove the reference to FSharp.Core and re-add the correct version from the list of assemblies.